# How to install AMD drivers in a offline installation

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon, amd-graphics-card

I am trying to find the drivers for the **Sapphire HD 5550 1G D2** from a reliable source (preferably from the official site) so I can install them on a computer that cannot connect to the internet. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download manually from any connected computer, then copy over by local network, USB stick etc

Official Driver download page - http://support.amd.com/en-us/download
Latest drivers for cards old & new are listed down the right-hand side.